# System.ArgumentException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to this awesome platform, I made very simple example it contains only one XAML page. Yesterday it worked flawlessly, but when ran it today, it threw this exception out of nowhere

This the exception:

[image: Exception]

HelloPage.xaml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SAP.HelloPage">

<!--  la configuration personalisé pour chaque system d'éxploitation   -->
   <ContentPage.Padding>
       <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
             iOS="0,10,0,0"
             Android="0,40,0,0">
      </OnPlatform>
   </ContentPage.Padding>  


  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" BindingContext="{x:Reference sliderID}">

     <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Suivant"/>

     <Label x:Name="lb_font"  Text="Font is :"/>


     <Slider Minimum="16" Maximum="45"  x:Name="sliderID"  ValueChanged="sliderID_ValueChanged"/>

     <Label x:Name="lb_quote"/>

  </StackLayout> 
<ContentPage>
```

HelloPage.xaml.cs :

```
public partial class HelloPage : ContentPage
{

   // quotes
   List<string> quotes = new List<string>()
   {
       "Bienvenu, la première paragraphe",
       "une autre quote, cella j'adore",
       "La troisième est magnifique"
   };

   int pos = 0;

   public HelloPage()
   {
        InitializeComponent();

        // settings initialisation
         lb_quote.Text = quotes.ElementAt(0);
  }


private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(pos == quotes.Count)
    {
        pos = 0;
    }

    lb_quote.Text = quotes.ElementAt(pos);
    pos += 1;

 }

private void sliderID_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lb_font.Text ="Font Size : " + sliderID.Value.ToString();
    lb_quote.FontSize = sliderID.Value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This one is quite subtle and hard to catch (well, actually it isn't hard to catch; just put a `try/catch` around `InitializeComponent` and you can examine the exception).

XAML is declarative which makes us believe that the order of attributes of a control does not matter. Unfortunately, since at some point the declarative XAML **will** be turned into a sequence of property assignments, the order of attributes **does** matter and it's the order of your `Slider` attributes that is causing your exception to be thrown.

You can imagine your `Slider` being constructed the following way:

```
var slider = new Slider();
slider.Minimum = 16;
slider.Maximum = 45;
...
```

But `Slider.Minimum` and `Slider.Maximum` seem to check if the values passed are valid.

When your code begins, the value of `Maximum` defaults to `0`. But before its value can be assigned, `Minimum`'s value is assigned a value of `16`.

At this moment your `Minimum` value (16) is greater than the default `Maximum` value (0) and hence an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown.

To solve it, just set the `Maximum` before the `Minimum` value and it does work.

Comment: it makes sense now, thank you , you are right , it works

Comment: I'd say, the implementation of `Slider` is broken

Answer (score 2):

As @Paul mentioned. Wrap it with try-catch and it gives more details about the exception. I spent few hours before figuring out to do that